# sagemath: How to find the right import library names for writing a python prog to load from sage

Tags: python, python-import, sage

Newbie to SageMath. Tried out different things from the Console & it worked fine. Now I want to automate into Python Program.

The same function which I call from the sage console is giving a `NameError: name '<xxxx>' is not defined`. I am assuming I have to import some modules in my python program. But there doesn't seem to be an easy way to figure out which one to import.

For e.g. in Java, let's say I want to use HashMap, I just google HashMap java & the first hit I get is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Which clearly tells me that I have to import it from java.util.

I can't find something similar for sagemath.

Now this is the code I want to call from my sagemath python program

c = <somenumber>
n = <somenumber>

r = Modular(c, n).sqrt()

I obviously get the error
`NameError: name 'Modular' is not defined`

How do I find out what I have to import to fix this error?

I googled for sagemath `Modular` and went through a couple of pages of results & I couldn't find what I have to import in an easy way.

Obviously, my first priority here is to figure out what to import for calling `Modular` & `sqrt` but the bigger question is how to do this everytime.

How is this done by sagemath users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `Mod` and not `Modular`.

To get the correct import statements, in a Sage session, try:

```
sage: import_statements(Mod)
```

which will suggest:

```
from sage.rings.finite_rings.integer_mod import Mod
```

Comment: Yes, it's Mod not Modular.